# Mongodb Java cmd find().pretty() not working

Tags: java, android, mongodb

I have Mongo set up and running. I have a problem where I cannot see any data being created in Mongo client in cmd prompt.

I am using Mongo 3.2.1 Java driver and Android Studio.

I have connected the port, address and working. Using the code below to create a database and collection works. But when I save the data it's not being saved (sometimes it works and sometimes not) and I don't know why.

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("xxx.xxx.x.x", xxxxx);
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("testdb");

    try {

        database.createCollection("cars");
    } catch (MongoCommandException e) {

        database.getCollection("cars").drop();
    }

    List<Document> writes = new ArrayList<>();

    MongoCollection<Document> carsCol = database.getCollection("cars");

    Document d1 = new Document("_id", 1);
    d1.append("name", "Audi");
    d1.append("price", 52642);
    writes.add(d1);

    Document d2 = new Document("_id", 2);
    d2.append("name", "Mercedes");
    d2.append("price", 57127);
    writes.add(d2);

    Document d3 = new Document("_id", 3);
    d3.append("name", "Skoda");
    d3.append("price", 9000);
    writes.add(d3);

    Document d4 = new Document("_id", 4);
    d4.append("name", "Volvo");
    d4.append("price", 29000);
    writes.add(d4);

    Document d5 = new Document("_id", 5);
    d5.append("name", "Bentley");
    d5.append("price", 350000);
    writes.add(d5);

    Document d6 = new Document("_id", 6);
    d6.append("name", "Citroen");
    d6.append("price", 21000);
    writes.add(d6);

    Document d7 = new Document("_id", 7);
    d7.append("name", "Hummer");
    d7.append("price", 41400);
    writes.add(d7);

    Document d8 = new Document("_id", 8);
    d8.append("name", "Volkswagen");
    d8.append("price", 21600);
    writes.add(d8);

    carsCol.insertMany(writes);


    MongoIterable<String> dbs = mongoClient.listDatabaseNames();
    System.out.println("The Following are your Databases!");
    for(String checkDBS : dbs){
        System.out.println(checkDBS);
    }

    mongoClient.close();

}
```

After running the above I check the data by querying them but it doesn't seem to do anything. Sometimes it shows and at times, the commands don't do anything.

[image: Cmd]

**UPDATED** ===============================================================

It does actually stores the data but I still cant query using cmd but I tried querying with Java and it worked

```
   iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
        @Override
        public void apply(final Document document) {
            System.out.println(document);
        }
   });
```

[image]

I don't know why cmd does not work.

Comment: Are you sure collection is not empty??

Comment: its empty but saving the data sometimes work and not

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read ur question completely, just read now, ur code is okay, can u try only insert not insert many

Comment: carsCol.insertOne(writes); I tried this already unfortunately the same

Comment: just re-install to mongo 3.6 still the same :s

Comment: This is not mongodb issue, i'm traveling, let me get to my laptop

Comment: In your mongo shell command, you only need to say `use testdb; db.cars.find().pretty()`. If you type `use cars` you will change to another db, `use` is to switch database, not collection.

Comment: you are right, my letter "d" key was not working. My apologies. Thanks @Wan Bachtiar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MongoShell you are using different DB than in your program.

You are trying to list all records in the **cars** database. But the collection *cars* is in the **testdb** database.

Proper sequence is:

```
use testdb
db.cars.find().pretty()
```

and you'll see your records.

Comment: yes thanks for your answer, I realized my mistake yesterday. "Use" is only refer to databases. Hope it can help others, I am new to Mongo so it could help new users.